# Easiest method to perform sensitivity analysis on 2D data-set - Matlab prefered

Tags: matlab

I have a hypothetical set of data and I would like to know of a simple way of studying the importance of two variables on a result.

The hypothetical experiment:

Each day for 100 days I do 2 exercises, A: pull-ups (between 1 and 10 in number), and B: push-ups (again between 1 and 10 in number). Each day I record how many cups of water I drink, Y.

Is there a relatively simple method of figuring out which of the two variables has the greater influence on Y?

From what I have seen there is a lot of options such as Sobel Sensitivity Indices, but it all looks a little over-kill for what I am after.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Rob

Comment: long before I had come across a good resource called MUCM toolkit which I had used to write 2D sensitivity analysis. Sadly the site seems to be down. I have the matlab code though which I ll be answering below. You can try with that and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for sensitivity analysis for 2 inputs and 1 output which fits your case and I had implemented 2 years ago. Sadly I do not have the paper or the online resource(called MUCM toolkit, link seems to be down) which I used to implement this. Below, `x1` and `x2` are the inputs, make sure you normalise the inputs from 0-1. No need to normalise the output(`f_D`). Give this a whirl and hoping it works for you :)

```
clear variables

%solar constant
x1 = [0.86  0.27 0.57 0.5 0.14 0.23 0.39 0.93 0.98 0.54 0.77 0.81 0.18 ... 
    0.71 0.31 0.04 0.69 0.4 0.63 0.08 0.34 0.04 0.83 0.21 0.67 0.47 0.14 ... 
    0.51 0.75 0.95 ];
% 0.00  0.83 0.16   0.37    0.76    0.64    0.58    0.91    0.42    0.21];
%albedo effect
x2 = [0.7 0.97 0.29 0.77 0.73 0.11 0.21 0.45 0.05 0.9 0.52 0.33 0.56 ...
    0.84 0.49 0.09 0.19 0.37 0.64 0.86 0.45 0.58 0.75 0.84 0.37 0.99 0.15 ...
    0.66 0.07 0.24 ];
% 0.12  0.83 0.51   0.64    0.44    0.70    0.46    0.03    0.24    0.94];

% x1 = randn(1,numel(x2));
% x2 = randn(1,numel(x2));

f_D = [11.81 -4.95 25.51 5.27 4.85 30.28 27.50 20.89 34.50 0.43 17.59   25.27 ... 
    13.39 3.67 16.50 29.96 29.78 21.14 12.78 -0.98 17.99 12.11 9.10 1.03 ... 
    22.71 -4.61 28.33 11.60 34.10 29.28 ]';

% 28.66 4.68 15.04  11.63   20.39   10.83   18.78   34.76   26.60   -4.08]';

% f_D = randn(1,numel(x2))';
% D = normalise(x_o); % normalise input data
D = [x1 ; x2]; % Already normalised

% Initialise few parameters
n = size(D, 2); % Number of observations per input
p = size(D,1); % Number of inputs
q = 1 + p; % Number of parameters in linear regression


y_mean = mean(f_D);
y_var = var(f_D);
y = (f_D - y_mean)/sqrt(y_var);


delta = [0.4966 0.1061];
A =   covariance_(D,D, delta);


H = [ones(1,n); D]';
A_inv = inv(A);

beta_t1 = inv(H' * A_inv * H);
beta_t2 = H' * A_inv * f_D;
beta = beta_t1 * beta_t2;

s_t1 = ((n-q-2) ^ -1);
s_t2 = inv(A) - inv(A) * H * inv(H' * inv(A) * H) * H' * inv(A);

% sig_hat_sq = s_t1 * f_D' * s_t2 * f_D;
sig_hat_sq = sigma_hat_sq(n,q,A,H,f_D);


y_fit = beta(1) + beta(2) * D;

xn = 0:.01:1;
x_new = xn;

for k = 1:numel(xn)
    xt_i = [xn(k) xn(k)]';

    pm_t1 = covariance_(D,xt_i,delta)';
    pm_t2 = A_inv * (f_D - (H * beta));
    mean_star(k) = h(xt_i)' * beta + (pm_t1 * pm_t2);

    for j = 1:numel(xn)
        xt_j = [xn(j) xn(j)]';
        pcv_t1 = covariance_(xt_i,xt_j,delta) ;
        pcv_t2 = covariance_(D,xt_i,delta)' * A_inv *  covariance_(D,xt_j,delta);
        pcv_t3 = h(xt_i)' - (covariance_(D,xt_i,delta)' * A_inv * H);
        pcv_t4 = inv( H' * A_inv * H);
        pcv_t5 = (h(xt_j)' -  covariance_(D,xt_j,delta)' * A_inv * H)';

       pcv_all = pcv_t1 - pcv_t2 + (pcv_t3 * pcv_t4 * pcv_t5);
       cov_star(k,j) = sig_hat_sq * pcv_all;
    end
end


conf_int = diag(cov_star)';

% beta  
% sig_hat_sq  
% delta
H_ = H;
beta_hat = beta;
% temp = ((f_D-H_*beta_hat)'* A_inv * (f_D-H_*(beta_hat)))/(n-q-2.);

% % Sensitivity Analysis - Code 


B = [[50, 0]; [0, 50]];
m = [0.5 0.5]';
C = [(delta(1) ^ -2 ) 0 ; 0 (delta(2) ^ -2 )];

v = 0; %nugget term 


% xn = 0:.01:1;
% xn = [xn' xn'];
xn = D;
R = [1 ; m];
e = A_inv * (f_D - H * beta_hat);
for j = 1:n  
    for w = 1:p
        w_bar = mod(w+2,2) + 1; % to be tuned for n dimenstion 
        all_w = [w w_bar];
        all_w = sort(all_w, 'ascend');
        R_w = 1; 
        xw = D(w,j); 
        R_w(w + 1) = xw;
        R_w(w_bar + 1) = m(w_bar);
        for k = 1:n   
            T_w(k) = Tval_w(k,xw, D, B, C, m, v, w, w_bar);         
        end
        Post_M_w(w,j) = R_w * beta_hat + T_w * e;
    end
end
w = 1;
plot(D(w,:), Post_M_w(w,:),'b.');
hold on
w = 2;
plot(D(w,:), Post_M_w(w,:),'r.');
ylabel('Average Effect');
xlabel('data x');
legend('solar constant', 'albedo');

figure
plot(x1,f_D,'.')

figure
plot(x2,f_D,'.')

test = 1;
```

---

```
function cov_ = covariance_(D,D_tilde, delta)

m = size(D,2);
n = size(D_tilde,2);
c = zeros(m,n);
t1 = c;
for p = 1:size(D,1)
    x = D(p,:);
    x_tilde = D_tilde(p,:);
    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
            c(i,j) = (x(i)-x_tilde(j));
        end
    end
    t2 = (c/delta(p)) .^ 2;
    t1 = t1 + t2;
end


cov_ =  exp(-t1);

end
```

---

```
function sq = sigma_hat_sq(n,q,A,H,f_D)

s_t1 = ((n-q-2) ^ -1);
s_t2 = inv(A) - inv(A) * H * inv(H' * inv(A) * H) * H' * inv(A);

sq =   s_t1 * f_D' * s_t2 * f_D;
```

---

```
function h_val = h(x)

h_val = [1 x']';

end
```

---

```
function tw = Tval_w(k,xw, x, B, C, m, v, w, w_bar)

temp = zeros(1,numel(w_bar));
for temp = 1:numel(w_bar)
    i = w_bar(temp);
    e1 = exp(-0.5*((2*C(i, i)*B(i, i))/(2*C(i, i) + B(i, i))) ... 
        * ((x(i,k)-m(i)) ^ 2));

    e2 = exp(-0.5 * (xw-x(w,k))*2*C(w,w)*(xw-x(w,k)));

    t1 = sqrt(B(i,i))/sqrt(2*C(i,i) + B(i,i));
    temp(i) = t1 * e1 * e2;   
end

tw = (1-v) * prod(temp);

end
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much harshkn. I will have a look at this right away :-) Thank you.

Comment: Hi, harshkn. Mind having a quick look at the code? There is an error in line 68 with an un-defined variable 'h'?

Comment: Can you print the whole line, where the error is ? coz the line number is not the same with me. Also coz there is no variable called 'h' . only H is present

Comment: Line 66 sorry :-).     mean_star(k) = h(xt_i)' * beta + (pm_t1 * pm_t2);

Comment: Thank you! It looks like there could be 1 more missing: Tval_w. Possibly Post_M_w too.

Comment: Damn! Added. So sorry, The code folder was all mixed and was difficult to know which belonged to this. Let me know if I missed any.

Comment: Add working :-) Truly, thank you so much. Especially with having to look and re-look to find the functions. If you are ever in Bristol England there is a beer with your name on it!

Comment: Welcome :) glad very old work of mine is still useful :) Keep an eye on `delta = [0.4966 0.1061];` , they are magic numbers. I will try to update it with the link from MUCM toolkit in which there provide a function to compute the values for finding delta. Haha thanks! :)